# Associating accounts not working

Tags: support, linked-accounts

I have accounts on several SE sites, and at least a little spend time on 8 of them. I've noticed that not all my accounts are synced with the others.

When I try to associate accounts, I'll get the error box "User ID [blah] already associated with another account". How do I fix this?

Sorry if this is incomplete, I'm unsure what information I need to provide. OpenID gives me a headache!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typically means that at some point in the past, you have had multiple duplicate accounts on an individual site.

(hint: try to use the same credentials on every site.. if you use Google on one, and Facebook on another, it is very difficult for us to figure out that's the same person)

The fix is easy: on your user page on the **accounts tab** click "clear all associations", then re-associate by clicking the big buttons next to each account.